# Retrofit GET returns null using @path with integer

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, wordpress-rest-api

Retrofit returns null whenever using with initialised integer but returns data when calling directly with integer number...
I'm using @path to access the data of WordPress-rest-api

This is My interface

```
public interface ImageDataApi {

String BASE_URL = "https://dwarkawala.com/index.php/wp-json//wp//v2//";

@GET("media/{Id}")
Call<Thumbnail> getImageData(
        @Path("Id") int postId
);



class ImageFactory {
    private static ImageDataApi service;
    public static ImageDataApi getInstance() {

        if (service == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
            service = retrofit.create(ImageDataApi.class);
            return service;
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

And i'm calling like this , it returns null all the time

```
int number = post.getId();
    ImageDataApi.ImageFactory.getInstance().getImageData(number).enqueue(new Callback<Thumbnail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Thumbnail> call, retrofit2.Response<Thumbnail> response) {

            Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(response.body()));


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Thumbnail> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

But when i call directly like this, it works...

```
ImageDataApi.ImageFactory.getInstance().getImageData(3658).enqueue(new Callback<Thumbnail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Thumbnail> call, retrofit2.Response<Thumbnail> response) {

            Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(response.body()));


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Thumbnail> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I don't get it where the error happens please help...

Comment: Did you check the result of `post.getId()`? Might not be what you expect

Comment: @Fred its gives same integer that i called directly

Comment: Then I don't know what's happening. Everything seems to check out.